Render Layers Output Alpha Issue/Artifacts
The goal is to render in separate layers for compositing in After Effects. I need to get 3 sequences as output (one sequence with alpha for each render layer).
I have 3 render layers:
1. SCENE
2. SMOKE
3. MUZZLE
However, Blender’s output looks different from what I see in Blender’s own compositing (see images). It also looks strange in Photoshop and After Effects. I suspect there’s an issue with the alpha channel, but I can’t figure out how to fix it.


This specific things are semi transparent, because of that it is recommended to render those with a black background and then add them on top of your scene in After effect with a different layer mode, like screen or multiply

There is a node behind File Output, what is it ? Are you sure you plugged the same thing into the File Output, the Viewer and the Composite nodes ? How is it "strange" in PS and AE ? Without seing it, I can't say anything about it.

There are also problems with file format being 8bit PNG. It will have view transform baked into it so it's unusable for compositing. You should do compositing in linear color space preferably with formats containing more data like EXR with 16 or 32 bit per channel color depth.

I mean in addition to what Emir already pointed out - basically the fact that you cannot composite various light effects with alpha only, but need other mathematical operations like addition and/or multiplication.

@Emir, thanks! but what about smoke? what's wrong with it?

@Lutzi it’s just the Viewer Node to show how it looks in compositing. in PS and AE, they look the same as in the screenshot (see image callout)

@MartynasŽiemys thanks! yeah, i tried PNG in 16-bit and EXR, but the result is still the same

It seems you did ignore everything else discussed in the comments though.

I don't think 8-bit is an issue there, it works if you don't change colors&exposure too much. There could be some color banding yes, but not "wrong" alpha. If there is no color grading afterwards, there shouldn't be any issue (assuming OP is exporting to 8-bit video/image).

@MartynasŽiemys sorry, what do you mean by "ignore everything else"? could you please tell me exactly what i can do with the smoke to get it right in the output? i'll try it right away

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html#id4 This is how you composite render passes. It's confusing since volume passes are not shown, but they are the same as others. Compositing needs to be done in linear color space (EXR saves in linear Rec709 color space and in 16 or 32 bits suitable for compositing). Smoke is volumes - you add volume direct and indirect to the image same as emission. You cannot composite volume(smoke) or emission(muzzle flashes) passes with alpha. Sorry, I was hoping someone else might take the time to answer in full as an official answer.

thanks a lot @MartynasŽiemys! so, if i have some color correction and effects done in blender's compositing, i can't just export it as it is, right? i have to export raw passes and then combine them in AE with additional color correction and effects? sounds like it's a bit trickier than i thought
